# Excel, how to dynamically modify column cells until next different value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For example:

[image]

I want it to become:

[image]

This clearly has to be done dynamically.

Comment: This can't be done without a helper column and then copy/pasting the result to the initial column. If you'll allow VBA, add the `vba` tag right below your post.

Comment: Absolutely as @VBasic2008 sir has said, you need helper column if you want to use a formula, otherwise use either `VBA` or `POWER QUERY`

Comment: With formula using a helper columns you may try this way `=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)=1,A1,A1&"_"&COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)-1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Office 365 you could create the required result in a different column/sheet with this formula: `=A1:A11&IF(COUNTIF(OFFSET(A1,,,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A1:A11),),),A1:A11)-1=0,"","_"&COUNTIF(OFFSET(A1,,,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A1:A11),),),A1:A11)-1)`

Or using `LET`:

```
=LET(data,A1:A11, 
     countif,COUNTIF(OFFSET(data,,,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(data))),data)-1,
     data&IF(countif=0,"","_"&countif))
```

[image]

If you want the data replaced with the amended data you need a VBA solution